# PhotoScroller iOS app memory leak in iPad 3.2 Simulator & Device

Tags: ios, ipad, memory

I was planning to develop an app based on PhotoScroller iOS app from Apple Developer. But what I found is when the PhotoScroller loads the 3 photos in scrollview - in Instrument it shows 28+ MB memory allocated, and swiping through the images increases memory use and eventually crashes. The sample app have no problem in iOS 4+ simulator and device and only allocates 1-2 MB memory.

Does anyone have any idea what's actually happening, or how to solve this. We are planning to develop an app which will be supported from 3.2 iPad onwards.